# Fabric wrapping using imagemajick

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation

Im new to ImageMajick. Is there a way to be able to wrap a fabric(pattern) on a plain object using Imagemajick.

Something like http://www.liquidpixels.com/demos/demos.m?name=Norwalk

I would like to programtically implement the above example so that I can choose a swatch and change the fabric of the object.

Any example close to the above implemented in ImageMajick would be highly appreciated

Regards,
Loveleen

Comment: Does it need to be imagemagick? Can it be some other free toolkit -- for, example a .NET one?

Comment: No, it doesnt have to be imagemagick. That was the closest I could find that felt could meet my requirement.

Comment: Hi Loveleen, can you please share it in details ..how you achieved this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the site you linked, they are doing much more than just some image manipulation.  It really looks like they have a 3-D model of the item, and are doing a texture wrap.

You could try to do something simple, but for complex patterns it won't look right (look at the way the patterns look over the arms, for example -- especially on chairs).

The simple thing to do is to start with a grayscale version of the picture with no texture -- just the shadow, and then use that as a mask onto a pattern.  The pattern will automatically be shaded properly by the gray mask.

Disclaimer: I work for Atalasoft, and I used our free [DotImage Photo](http://www.atalasoft.com/free-dotnet-image-sdk) product to get the sample below just playing around (you could do better if you try it out)

1. Take the couch and make it grayscale (keep it 24 bpp, but with only gray)
2. Make a version of the fabric that is the same size as the image
3. Use OverlayMergedCommand with MergeOption set to Photoshop.  What that does is merge pixels onto the couch based on the gray level -- it leaves white alone.  The color won't match exactly, but you have to play with that -- there are lots of commands to try -- you could adjust the hue.  Also, if you start with a gray levels that are darker or lighter the effect will be different.

[image]

I don't know ImageMagick, but I would start here for a similar feature

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#overlay

Comment: Thank you. I created a shadow mask and was able to achieve a similar effect using GD library.

Comment: Check out the tutorial and demo here http://loveleenkaur.com/leisure/uncategorized/fabric-wrapping/

Comment: @LoveleenKaur link is broken can you share

Answer (score 2):

While it is true that LiquidPixels is doing a full texture map, we do not have a cad drawing of the couch (or whatever product). We provide our customers with a proprietary tool for creating a pseudo 3D model from a standard 2D photo. The tool uses a simple interface with an overlaid grid to enable you to create the pseudo 3D representation of the product (the sofa in this case). Once this is generated, you can easily drape any fabric onto it and see the resulting texture mapping. Feel free to contact us for more information. http://www.liquidpixels.com/contact/

Answer (score 1):

Demo is http://loveleenkaur.com/projects/watermark: The code is as follows:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['src'])){ ?>
<img src="watermark.php?src=<?php if(isset($_GET['src'])){echo $_GET['src'];} ?>" />
<?php } else { ?>
<img src="watermark.php?src=pattern.jpg" />
<?php } ?>
<table>
<tr>
<td><a href="?src=pattern.jpg"><img src="pattern.jpg" width="50" height="50" style="border:none" /></a></td>
<td><a href="?src=pattern2.jpg"><img src="pattern2.jpg" width="50" height="50" style="border:none" /></a></td>
<td><a href="?src=pattern3.jpg"><img src="pattern3.jpg" width="50" height="50" style="border:none" /></a></td>
<td><a href="?src=pattern4.jpg"><img src="pattern4.jpg" width="50" height="50" style="border:none" /></a></td>
<td><a href="?src=pattern5.jpg"><img src="pattern5.jpg" width="50" height="50" style="border:none" /></a></td>
<td><a href="?src=pattern6.jpg"><img src="pattern6.jpg" width="50" height="50" style="border:none" /></a></td>
<td><a href="?src=pattern7.jpg"><img src="pattern7.jpg" width="50" height="50" style="border:none" /></a></td>
<td><a href="?src=pattern8.jpg"><img src="pattern8.jpg" width="50" height="50" style="border:none" /></a></td>
<td><a href="?src=pattern9.jpg"><img src="pattern9.jpg" width="50" height="50" style="border:none" /></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```